# Copy my user account's wp-admin dashboard layout to other users?

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

On the Dashboard tab in wp-admin in my user account, I have certain items hidden in Screen Options and I have the panels arranged in a particular way.

I want to copy the same layout to my other administrative users, so that they can see certain information and so that I can more easily remotely explain things when I need to.

I assume that this information is contained in a database table.

What would I need to copy to where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Original code (License: MIT)

The following code is altered [from my "Meta Box Order debug" plugin](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/9100450) (available on GitHub as Gist). The explanation can be found in the code comments.

#### Benefit

The nice thing with this solution is, that it does *not* alter the DB values, but alters the data on the fly. This way you can any time revert the changes and/or use another user as "data origin".

Another benefit is, that you can add a single dummy user that you simply use as blueprint. Every time you want to change the layout for everyone, simply log in with this user and alter the meta boxes on the dashboard. This way you can alter the configuration without writing a single line of code.

#### @TODO

You will have to change the user ID - this is marked as `@TODO` - to the user ID that you actually want to clone from/use as "origin".

```
<?php

namespace WPSE;

/**
 * Plugin Name: (#144583) Clone Meta Box Order
 */

add_filter( 'get_user_metadata', 'WPSE\disableMetaBoxOrder', 10, 4 );
function disableMetaBoxOrder( $abort, $userID, $key, $single )
{
    // Too early: abort
    if (
        ! function_exists( 'get_current_screen' )
        OR NULL === get_current_screen()
        OR ! property_exists( get_current_screen(), 'base' )
    )
        return $abort;

    // Don't trigger on the wrong screens
    if ( 'dashboard' !== get_current_screen()->base  )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
        return $abort;
    }

    $target  = 'meta-box-order_dashboard';

    // This is the part that actually alters/clones the user data
    // Trigger on default as on site specific settings
    if (
        $key === $target
        OR $key === $GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix.$target
        )
    {
        // Prevent endless loop
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

        return get_user_meta(
            # @TODO Replace the next line with the user ID 
            # that you want to clone from (the origin)
            get_current_user_id(),
            $target,
            TRUE
        );
    }

    return $abort;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying, lol.  I cannot figure out where to add the user ID, which is 7.

Comment: @paradroid Exactly where I added the `@TODO`-comment in the code. `get_current_user_id()` should be replaced by the User ID (or better: a function that returns the ID of the user) you want to clone from.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand.  I replaced `get_current_user_id(),` with `7,`, but of course it didn't work.

Comment: I currently do not have a WP installation around to test this, but you can remove the above `if` statements to see if they are blocking things. Keep in mind that this is for the `dashboard` and the meta box order.

Comment: I tried removing the `if` statements, but it still didn't work.  :/

Comment: I just saw the docblock above, which tells me that I tried it and it works. Make sure to test it in a vanilla WP install with a default theme and plugins deactivated.

Comment: For clarity, is this how I add the user ID?  http://pastebin.com/0WLmtzu9

Comment: @paradroid read the PHP comment in code you postet. There you need to add the ID instead of the 7.

Comment: But the user ID of the account that I want to clone the dashboard layout from is 7.

Comment: @paradroid In theory, you _can_ leave the code as is. Still, it's better to identify the user by its name or email. I would suggest to add a dummy-user via some small custom plugin. Meaning: You enable the plugin, if the user is not there: add it. Then you can use [`get_user_by()' &(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) and fetch the user by its name or email. The return value is a `\WP_User` object, from which you can fetch the ID via `$user->ID`. That you can use instead the hard coded (unreliable) ID in the answer above.

Comment: This code does not work for all user options. You need to remove the $single argument in get_user_meta because the evaluation of the single argument is done after the get_user_metadata filter.

Comment: @Gfra54 You can [edit] the answer and improve on it. It's 9 years old and this site lives off of your contributions.

Comment: @kaiser thanks, just did. been here for 20 years, never knew you could edit other peoples messages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the Database in the `{$prefix}usermeta` table. There is a field named:

```
meta-box-order_dashboard
```

You'll need to poke around and get some more fields however. There are a number of other tables which store dashboard panes and states, this i cant guess at as depending on your user base, plugins, etc.. the values you'll need will depend on that.

The majority of `usermeta` is dedicated to these and other administrative settings.